Where did the multiline expression evaluation dialog do in IntelliJ 2024.1?
Before 2024.1 there was a dialog (I assume "Evaluate Expression", Alt + Shift + 8) which allowed writing and pasting multiline expression for the Kotlin Debugger.
2024.1 only allows single line which causes an insane loss of time while scrolling through the line and formatting multiline expressions from the code which do not compile as single line statements - often involving copying and editing everything in an external text editor.
I assume the feature was moved because that's too much of a painful regression to make it into a release.

Please check: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2024.1/examining-suspended-program.html#evaluate-arbitrary-expression
In the Evaluate dialog, modify the selected expression or enter a new one in the Expression field. Click Expand Shif tEnter to modify a multiline code fragment.


Thanks. The regression afaik is that the input no longer expands when a multiline statement is inserted which is quite helpful and make the dialog intuitive.
